# Return Type Based on User Selection?

Tags: java, inheritance, return-type

Ok a fairly difficult Question to phrase but this is the best I can come up with.

Basically I have an Animal Class, an Insect Class which inherits from the Animal Class, and a Spider, Woodlouse and Worm class which inherit from the Insect Class

Say for example I have a class called InsectStorage which defines and stores a number of Insect objects in an array (so an array of different species of worms, woodlouses etc). And I want the user to be able to select an insect and have an insect assigned for the player within this class.

Setting the insect is achievable enough with

```
Spider blackWidow = new Spider()
Spider wolfSpider = new Spider()
Spider[] spiderStorage = new Spider[2]

worm lumbricusTerrestris = new Worm()
...
switch (insectSelect)

case: "Black Widow"
```

So the switch statement is where the first complication arises but is just about solvable by creating a selectedPlayerInsect of type Worm, Spider and Woodlouses and setting each one based on selection.

But how could I possibly create a getPlayerInsect() method? I would need to be able to return a Spider if a spider is selected, and a Worm if a worm is selected.

I could try making a playerObject for each insect subclass and creating four getPlayerXX() methods but that would mean every time I wanted to call getPlayerSpider() or getPlayerWorm() within my main method I would have to put if statements in to check which object had been selected (which would be highly inconvenient).

I tried fiddling around with Wrapper classes but couldn't make those work either (as I would still to use if playerIsWorm etc).

Alot of text, not much code, but I dont think code is really needed with my explanation.
How can I (if I can) solve this Issue?

Comment: This is really tangential to the question, but are you aware that _none_ of your `Insect` examples are actually insects?

Comment: What is the type of the array in `InsectStorage` class?

Comment: This is a typical [**polymorphic**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) situation.  You declare your collection as super-class (or better interface) and Java calls the appropriate method of a derived class.

Comment: @ajb "I find this pork chop shallow and pedantic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to solve your problem immediately is by doing type checking - basically what you said. It's ugly, but based on what you have in mind it works.

However, I think there is a deeper problem to think about.

If you design your classes properly, the actual 'type' of the Insect class shouldn't matter. You should  build the different logic into the subclasses themselves. This makes it easier to build on top in the future. @PM 77-1 said it best - you need to use polymorphism the way it should be used.

So instead, just have:

```
public Insect getPlayerInsect(){
  return playerInsect;
}
```

Maybe your main method looks something like this:

```
Insect player = getPlayerInsect();
player.eat(); // Everything eats
```

You don't need (shouldn't) to build complicated if/else logic into that eat statement.

```
abstract class Insect {
  abstract void eat();
}

class Spider extends Insect{
  @Override
  public void eat(){
    //eat dung
  }
}

class Worm extends Insect {
  @Override
  public void eat(){
    //eat soil
  }
}
```

You delay the decision making until the very end - until the method actually gets called. This way you reuse functionality and don't need to write lots of complicated if/else statements.

If you need to add other functionality to your insect player object, you just add them and override them appropriately.

If you find that `eat` doesn't apply to all subclasses, then it usually means you need to remodel your class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can uses Clases/Enums for the different types of insects.

```
Enum Spiders {BLACKWIDOW, WOLFSPIDER};

Spider firstSpider = Spiders.BLACKWIDOW;
if (firstSpider == Spiders.BLACKWIDOW) ...
```

vs.

```
class BlackWidow extends Spider {... }
class WolfSpider extends Spider { ... }
Spider firstSpider = new BlackWidow();
if (firstSpider instanceof BlackWidow) ....
```

In that case you would test with instanceof or .class (for the Class case) or == for the Enum case. In your case when you have one class Spider you should give it a property with its name:

```
Spider blackWidow = new Spider("BlackWidow");
if (blackWidow.isType("BlackWidow)) ...
```

There would be a possibility to check for known instances with the == operator. But this is bad practice for actual domain classifications and hard to debug (and does not work with persisted identities):

```
public class Spiders {
  final Spider BLACKWIDOW = new Spider();
  final Spider WOLFSPIDER = new Spider();

  void doSpiderThing(Spider userSelection) {
    if (userSelection == BLACKWIDOW) {
    ...

  void selectSpiderByName(String spiderName) {
    if ("Tekla".equals(spiderName))
        doSpiderThing(BLACKWIDOW);
    ...
```

Or similiar. You asked in comments how you can return spider or work, you would do that by returning a super-type of both (by default Object, but better something specific):

```
interface Animal {String getSpecies(); }
Enum AnimalEnum implements Animal {
  BLACKWIDOW { getSpecies() {return "Spider"; }},
  WOLFSPIDER { getSpecies() {return "Spider"; }},
  WORM { getSpecies() {return "Worm"; }}
} 

Animal getAnimalBySelection(String input) {
 if ("worm".equalsIgnoreCase(input))
   return AnimalEnum.WORM;
  else ...
}
```

Comment: Ok so if I have an enum with spider objects and an enum with worm objects, But I want only One variable to contain the players selected object (which can be any of the insects). How can I return that object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want the "player" to be able to select the type of insect OBJECT (woodlouse, worm, spider) or the type of insect 'name' (for lack of a better term - Blackwidow, wolfspider,etc).

If the former, it seems you could utilize the getClass() method (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_getclass.htm) and compare that with your known classes in an enumerated list when creating the new insect for the player.

If the latter, eckes's answer seems to be appropriate.

Comment: It's best not to say things like "answer above" because StackOverflow rearranges the order all the time.  At the moment, your answer is above his.